# Angular - dynamically change Ionic CSS properties in [ngStyle]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use `[ngClass]` to dynamically change the `--bullet-background-active` color for the [Ionic Slide](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#css-custom-properties) based on this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-classes-with-ngclass-and-ngstyle#toc-using-the-ngstyle-binding).

```
<ion-slides pager="true" [ngStyle]="{'--bullet-background-active':BulletColorVar}">
```

However, it does not seem to work specifically for Ionic custom CSS properties.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: did you solved this problem? I have the same. Chrome comes up with this "ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" "

Answer (score 0):

try using `style.setProperty(propertyName, value, priority)` function

CSS

```
ion-slides {
   --bullet-background-active: --bullet-color-var
}
```

TS

```
document.body.style.setProperty('--bullet-color-var', BulletColorVar)
```